# How to save the added attribute with CKeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

i added ckeditor in my admin control panel.I'm making and saving text in italics or bold.And this change doesnt appear on the website.
what can i do this problem? 
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqL33.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GncT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that CKEditor is JavaScript application and it doesn't have anything to do with saving data on your server-side. Once data has been sent via Form or AJAX it is your server-side which further handles that.

You most likely have filters in your server-side code which filters out some or all the HTML.